# CreateIndex with Binding Objects

Tags: faunadb

I have a collection that includes a field of type Time. I need to be able to query this collection by year, or month-year combination.

I have tried using the index creation tool on the web site itself, using things like `Year(data.expDate)` and `Month(data.expDate)` in the Terms, but this did not work.

Here is the schema for my collection:

```
type Expense {
  _id: ID!
  expAmount: Float!
  expDate: Time!
  expCategory: Category!
  _ts: Long!
}
```

I need to be able to list the expenses for a particular year, or a particular month-year, without having to create separate month and year fields in my collection.

Answer (score 8):

The solution to this was creating an index based on computed fields, which are then bound as terms, something like:

```
CreateIndex({
  name: "expByYearMonth",
  source: [{
    class: Collection("Expense"),
    fields: {
      year:Query(Lambda("doc",Year(Select(["data","expDate"],Var("doc"))))),
      month:Query(Lambda("doc",Month(Select(["data","expDate"],Var("doc")))))
    }
  }],
  terms: [{ binding: "year" }, { binding: "month" }]
})
```

I was then able to search by year, month and get the results with something like:

```
Paginate( Match(Index('expByYearMonth'), [2019, 10]) )
```

(With special thanks to @colllin and the other helpful folks on the Fauna Slack channel, for pointing me in the right direction.)